# Could not show meal based on meal categories(Django)

Tags: python, django, api, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to show meal based on the meal categories. I am using django rest framework for Rest API. I can show meat but not based on categories. The models are Restaurant, Meal and Meal Cateogies.

here is my model

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="name of restaurant")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)

class Meal(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    meal_category = models.ForeignKey('MealCategory')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text="name of the meal")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MealCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text="name of the category of meal")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class MealCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # meal = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = MealCategory


class MealSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    meal_category = MealCategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meal

    def get_meal(self, obj):
        print('object of meal',obj)
        instance = MealCategory.objects.get(slug=str(obj.slug))
        meal_qs = instance.meal_set.filter(available=True)
        meal = MealSerializer(meal_qs, many=True).data
        return meal

class RestaurantSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    owner = SerializerMethodField()
    meal = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        read_only = ('id',)

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        return str(obj.owner)

    def get_meal(self, obj):
        print('object of meal',obj)
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(slug=str(obj.slug))
        meal_qs = restaurant.meal_set.filter(available=True)
        meal = MealSerializer(meal_qs, many=True).data
        return meal
```

my API right now looks like this

```
"meal": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "meal_category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "veg",
                    "slug": "veg"
                },
                "name": "Mushroom drumstick",
                "slug": "mushroom-drumstick",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "meal_category": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Non-veg",
                    "slug": "non-veg"
                },
                "name": "Ham Cheesy Burger",
                "slug": "ham-cheesy-burger",
                "restaurant": 1
            }
        ],
        "name": "Kathmandu Fast Food Center",
        "slug": "kathmandu-fast-food-center",
```

But I want meal to be shown like this

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"kathmandu fast food center",
    "slug": "kathmandu-fast-food-center",
    "meal_category":[
        {
            "Non veg":[
                "meal":[
                    {
                        "name":"Ham Burger"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Chicken BBQ"
                    }
                ]
            ],

            "Veg":[
                "meal":[
                    {
                        "name":"mushroom soup"
                    },

                    {
                        "name":"Aloo Drumstick"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please guide me how can i design such API.

Comment: You want to show that based on what serializer ? I mean,  Just show meals and in each meal its categories ?

Comment: I want to show based on meal category serializer. Which one will be the best way to show meal?